# Apache - Multi SSL certs voiding each other

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, https, virtual-host

I have on one of our servers two SSL certs running for two projects, one of which is a wildcard SSL issued to that domain only, which I'll call **domain2.com**. **domain1.com**, the other domain has the domain issued to one subdomain only, called *servers*.

Due to *domain2* allowing users on the project to create subdomains, it has a VirtualHost setup looking like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    <Directory /var/www/domain2>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    #There's a SSL redirection here -
    #stackexchange network detected it as a URL shortener, so removed from question
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /app/domain2/certs/domain2.com.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /app/domain2/certs/domain2.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/app/domain2/certs/fullchain.pem"
    SSLCACertificatePath "/app/domain2/certs/"
    SSLCACertificateFile "/app/domain2/certs/cacert.pem"
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine, however the *servers.domain1.com* SSL isn't working (which is issued on letsencrypt, domain2.com is issued with AlphaSSL

```
<VirtualHost servers.domain1.com:443>
    <Directory /app/corporate/mediaserver/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    #There's a SSL redirection here -
    #stackexchange network detected it as a URL shortener, so removed from question
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /app/corporate/mediaserver/certs/[redacted]
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /app/corporate/mediaserver/certs/[redacted]
    SSLCACertificatePath /app/corporate/mediaserver/certs/[redacted]
    SSLCACertificateFile /app/corporate/mediaserver/certs/[redacted]
    ServerName servers.domain1.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /app/corporate/mediaserver/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I load servers.domain1.com it tries to load in the SSL from the wildcard, however if I set the `<VirtualHost>` to `<VirtualHost domain1.com:443>` and load domain1.com it loads the SSL from the correct one (servers.domain1.com virtualhost just gets ignored).

[image: Loading servers.domain2.com (actual tld is .io)]

Comment: Do you have different IP addresses for each domain, or do they all share a single IP address?

Comment: They share the same IP address @grawity

Comment: Well that's your problem.

Answer (score 1):

First: The parameter in `<VirtualHost …>` does not work this way. In "one IP per domain" systems, it is meant for specifying which IP address the webserver will *bind to* (that is, what address it will receive connections on) for that virtual host. It is *not* for selecting the virtual host based on HTTP "Host:" or TLS SNI.

However, you say in comments that you only have a single IP address (so you'll want to use TLS SNI). In that case *all* virtual host blocks should bind to the same `*` address, and the actual domain name should be specified as `ServerName`.

Second: In Apache configuration, the first matching VirtualHost block wins. If you have a wildcard `ServerName` *above* exact matches, it will always be chosen. So make sure your VirtualHosts are ordered correctly.

```
# The specific subdomains go first...

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName servers.domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /app/corporate/mediaserver/public
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /app/corporate/mediaserver/certs/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /app/corporate/mediaserver/certs/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

# ...and the wildcard is last:

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias *.domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /app/domain2/certs/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /app/domain2/certs/domain2.com.key
</VirtualHost>
```

(The `SSLCertificateChainFile` setting is obsolete in Apache 2.4. The `SSLCA*` settings are for *client* authentication – if you don't use that, you do not need them either.)